# Facebook Tag image after uploading using Graph/REST API

Tags: php, facebook

After uploading an image, am trying to tag it but the "id" returned after uploading the image is of no use apparently.

Am wondering if anyone has been able to achieve the same?

```
function upload_image($file,$session,$message) {
    $args = array(
       'message' => $message,
    );
    $args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$album_id.'/photos?access_token='.$session['access_token'];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 


   $result = json_decode($data,true);

   $picture = $result['id'];

   print_r($picture);


    $json = 'https://api.facebook.com/method/photos.addTag?pid='.$picture.'&tag_text=Test&x=0&y=0&access_token='.$session['access_token'];

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = $json;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 

    print_r($data);




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a deficiency of the new Graph API. Through some experimenting and reading, it seems that there are two kinds of IDs for a photo on Facebook.

- new **Graph API** ID. This ID is only usable within Graph API calls. Since the photos.addTag is part of the old API, the ID you are passing it is invalid.
- old **REST API** ID. This ID is retrieved through REST API calls, i.e. **photos.get** or **photos.upload**

I have not found a way to convert from one kind of ID to another. This is pretty stupid, if you ask me.

I can think of two ways to upload and tag photos via API calls right now:

1. Upload the image using **photos.upload** and tag it using **photos.addTag**. This is probably the cleanest way to do it.
2. Upload the image using the Graph API call you have in your example, then uses **photos.get** to get a list of images, iterating through to find the one you just uploaded. This is method would allow you maintain the Graph API call, but it would be hackish at best.

Also, it seems that no matter what album ID I pass to the Graph API upload image call, it puts the uploaded image in a photo album titled "[Application Name] Photos".

One more thing, as far a scope/request permissions go, I seem to need **publish_stream** access to have the uploaded image instantly go live on the user's account. If you do not have **publish_stream** access, the image will need the user's approval before his or her friends can see it. You will need **user_photos** access to get the list of the user's photos for method #2.

Hope this information helps you out.

Relavent Links:

- Old REST API [photos.upload documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload)
- Old REST API [photos.addTag documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.addTag)
- Graph API [photo publishing](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo)
- [A forum post](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=59029) about the same problem that you are having

Comment: Brilliant reply. If I could upvote this multiple times, I would. Am going to check out everything and try once and let you know. My only worry is the old API will be deprecated shortly.

Answer (score 3):

Hey,
you can tag the Picture directly on the Upload with the GRAPH API,
see the example below:
This Method creates an array for the tag information, in this examples the method becomes an array with Facebook user Ids:

```
private function makeTagArray($userId) {
    foreach($userId as $id) {
          $tags[] = array('tag_uid'=>$id, 'x'=>$x,'y'=>$y);
          $x+=10;
          $y+=10;
      }
    $tags = json_encode($tags);
    return $tags;
}
```

Here are the arguments for the call of the GRAPH API to upload an picture:

```
$arguments = array(
                    'message' => 'The Comment on this Picture',
                    'tags'=>$this->makeTagArray($this->getRandomFriends($userId)),
                    'source' => '@' .realpath( BASEPATH . '/tmp/'.$imageName),
            );
```

And here is the Method for the GRAPH API call:

```
    public function uploadPhoto($albId,$arguments) {
    //https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos
    try {

       $fbUpload = $this->facebook->api('/'.$albId.'/photos?access_token='.$this->facebook->getAccessToken(),'post', $arguments);
       return $fbUpload;
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        $e;
       // var_dump($e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The argument $albId contains an ID from an Facebook Album.

And if you want to Tag an existing Picture from an Album you can user this Method:
At First we need the correct picture ID from the REST API, In this example we need the Name from an Album wich the Application has create or the user wich uses this Application.
The Method returns The Picture ID From the last Uploaded Picture of this Album:

```
public function getRestPhotoId($userId,$albumName) {
     try {
        $arguments = array('method'=>'photos.getAlbums',
                            'uid'=>$userId
            );
       $fbLikes = $this->facebook->api($arguments);
       foreach($fbLikes as $album) {

           if($album['name'] == $albumName) {
               $myAlbId = $album['aid'];
           }
       }
       if(!isset($myAlbId))
           return FALSE;
       $arguments = array('method'=>'photos.get',
                            'aid'=>$myAlbId
            );
       $fbLikes = $this->facebook->api($arguments);
       $anz = count($fbLikes);
       var_dump($anz,$fbLikes[$anz-1]['pid']);
       if(isset($fbLikes[$anz-1]['pid']))
           return $fbLikes[$anz-1]['pid'];
       else
           return FALSE;
       //var_dump($fbLikes[$anz-1]['pid']);
       //return $fbLikes;
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        $e;
       // var_dump($e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you have the correct picture ID From the REST API and you can make your REST API CALL to tag this Picture $pid is the Picture from the Method getRestPhotoId and $tag_uid is an Facebook userId:

```
    $json = 'https://api.facebook.com/method/photos.addTag?pid='.$pid.'&tag_uid='.$userId.'&x=50&y=50&access_token='.$this->facebook->getAccessToken();

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = $json;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

And this line is very important:
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, true);
you must youse CUROPT_GET instead of CUROPT_POST to add a Tag throw the REST API.

I Hope this helps you.

Best wishes Kay from Stuttart